# Write Data From .SAV to .CSV (header data missing)

Tags: r, csv, spss, r-haven

when I write my sav file into csv (using library(haven), read_sav and write.csv), it can export to csv file properly, but some of the text in my header is missing. For example, each header has a question number with some subtext describing the question in detail. After I write the data to csv the question number is still on the header, but the description is missing.

Comment: That‘s because the haven package can deal with and show the variable labels from .sav files, same with value labels. haven stores this as attributes for each column. A csv can‘t, so when exporting, this info just gets lost/deleted.

Comment: You should probably check the package `labelled`. It has some better ways of setting/extracting SPSSlike variable and value labels. E.g. with `var_label(YOUR DATA FRAME HERE)` you get all variable labels of your data.

Comment: Thank you!! The labelled package and `var_label()`worked. I used `read_spss()` , `var_label()`, and `write.csv()` to export the variable labels in the .csv format.